# Is this PSK or FSK

Tags: signal-analysis, modulation, analog

I am analysing a captured 433.92MHz signal sampled at 2MHz:
[image]

If we zoom in:

[image]

I am thinking this is PSK? Am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "this is what I get": Is this the real-valued signal, or is this amplitude or I or Q of an equivalent baseband? Are you sure you're sampling sufficiently? The jumps in some of the oscillations indicate there might be something else going on. Generally, the fact that this is non-continuous and doesn't seem to be on a common timebase might mean you're looking at whole packets of signal, and your filtering might have removed all the data. Again, with the amount of information we have, pure speculation. My guess is that this might be some PPM, or coded OOK, or something more esoteric alltogether.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are right, is this better?

Comment: OK, since I assume "434 MHz signal sampled at 2 MHz" means complex baseband, no: you haven't answered whether we're looking at I, Q, or magnitude in these plots.